# how to set a value in a map from Visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce

I've got a simple Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page  controller="MyVisualforcePageNameController" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0">    
  <apex:form>
    <apex:repeat value="{!testMap}" var="testKey">
        <apex:inputText value="{!testMap[testKey]}"/>
    </apex:repeat> 
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

and even simpler controller:

```
public with sharing class MyVisualforcePageNameController {
    public Map<Integer, String> testMap {get;set{if (value == null) this.WHAT_PROPERTY_NAME? = ''}}
    public MyVisualforcePageNameController() {
     ...fillingMap...
    }
}
```

I want to check if I received a null from visualforce page, I replace it with '' in a Map. What should I write instead of **WHAT_PROPERTY_NAME?**. For a single property I would've done something like:

```
String testStr {get;set {if (value == null) this.testStr == '';}}
```

Is there a way to do the same for a map or a list?

Comment: where are you filling map. you can put null check there. Or share your code.

Comment: The possiblitiy of doing such a trick is interesting. Ofcourse I could make several workarounds(i.e. call the function and pass id to it). But if there's exists a simple way - why not to use it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of your visualforce page is correct. The issue seems to lie in your understanding of how (and when) values from a form are passed back to your controller, and what a map setter does.

With your current visualforce, you can change the value corresponding to more than one of your map keys, but that data doesn't get immediately sent back to your controller when the input field loses focus. Instead, the entire map is overwritten when the form is submitted (which calls the `save()` method).

A map setter doesn't work one key value at a time, when you call a setter for a map, it takes an entire map as an argument. According to [this page of documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm), the setter has an implicit parameter called `value`.

The minimum change required to accomplish what you're looking to do is to change your setter so that it loops over the entire map passed as an argument to the setter.

```
public Map<Integer, String> testMap {
    get;
    set{
        for(String key :value.keySet()){
            if(value.get(key) == null){
                value.set(key, '');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm personally not too fond of defining accsessor methods in the declaration of class attributes, but it should work. I'm actually not 100% certain of the exact behavior of defining a setter method (does it completely override the standard setter? or is it run before/after the standard setter?). If this doesn't work out of the gate, you may need to try adding `testMap = (Map<Integer,String>)value;` at the end.

In the end, I think I'd suggest not pushing the not so well documented boundaries of standard features. Two nearly identical alternatives would be:

- Override the `save()` method of the standardController (assuming this is part of a controller extension), performing the exact same loop there (substituting `value` with `testMap`), and leaving the standard setter in place (instead of overriding it).
- Declare a `public void setTestMap(Map<Integer, String> input)` method, and make your class attribute declaration `Map<Integer, String> testMap {get;}`

**+edit:**

After [doing my own tests](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141156/what-is-the-behavior-of-a-class-attribute-setter-defined-inline), you would need to explicitly set `testMap = value;` at the end of your setter (there doesn't appear to be a need to do any type casting).

That said, I don't think there's much (if any) benefit to keeping this setter defined inline.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for. IMO, the inline setter is good  to override if we put the logic to an isolated method: something like `public Map<Integer, String> testMap {get; set{this.testMap = removeNullsFromMap(value)}}`