# What is the behavior of a class attribute setter defined inline?

Tags: apex, setter

This came up in my answer on [this other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141089/how-to-set-a-value-in-a-map-from-visualforce/141147#141147)

> I'm actually not 100% certain of the exact behavior of defining a setter method (does it completely override the standard setter? or is it run before/after the standard setter?)

Let's say that we have the below apex class as an example

```
public class MySetterTest{
    public Map<String, Integer> otherTestMap;
    public Map<String, Integer> testMap {
        public get;
        private set{
            // This setter method has access to an implicitly defined "value" parameter

            for(String key :value.keySet()){
                value.put(key, value.get(key) * -1);
            }
        }
    }

    public MySetterTest(){
        testMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
        otherTestMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void testAdd(String key, Integer val){
        otherTestMap.put(key, val);
        testMap = otherTestMap.clone();
    }
}
```

Does a setter, defined inline, behave the same way as defining a separate setter method (i.e. completely overrides the automatic setter the same as a `public void setTestMap(Map<String, Integer> input){...}` would)?

Or, does a setter, defined inline, simply add the setter block to a collection of setter blocks to be executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the example class provided, we can run it as anonymous apex along with the following snippet

```
MySetterTest mst = new MySetterTest();
system.debug('initial values: testMap = ' + mst.testMap + ' otherTestMap = ' + mst.otherTestMap);
mst.testAdd('first', 1);
system.debug('after call of testAdd: testMap = ' + mst.testMap + ' otherTestMap = ' + mst.otherTestMap);
mst.testAdd('second', 2);
system.debug('after call of testAdd: testMap = ' + mst.testMap + ' otherTestMap = ' + mst.otherTestMap);
```

Doing so yields the following debug statements

> |DEBUG|initial values: testMap = null otherTestMap = {}
>
> |DEBUG|after call of testAdd: testMap = null otherTestMap = {first=1}
>
> |DEBUG|after call of testAdd: testMap = null otherTestMap = {first=1, second=2}

This indicates that a setter, defined inline, does behave the same way as a setter defined as a stand-alone method.

Changing the example class's inline setter to add `testMap = value;`

```
private set{
    // This setter method has access to an implicitly defined "value" parameter

    for(String key :value.keySet()){
        value.put(key, value.get(key) * -1);
    }

    testMap = value;
}
```

and re-running the test produces the expected results

> |DEBUG|initial values: testMap = {} otherTestMap = {}
>
> |DEBUG|after call of testAdd: testMap = {first=-1} otherTestMap = {first=1}
>
> |DEBUG|after call of testAdd: testMap = {first=-1, second=-2} otherTestMap = {first=1, second=2}

In the end, I believe that having a proper setter method is better practice (and not that much more work) than trying to hijack the auto-generated setter.